# ajax call to webflow using get request

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-webflow, spring-js

I am able to use webflow with ajax using POST, but not with GET.

I have a parent object at the top of my page. I have a list  of potential children at the bottom of the page. The user selects the "add" link by a potential child to add to the parent.

Full formed html is as follows:

```html
<tr>
   <td><a href="/prototype2/xzcreatetesttype.html?execution=e2s1&amp;_eventId=addtut&amp;tutid=148&amp;tutname=Advanced%20French">Add</a></td>
 <td>Advanced French</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><a href="/prototype2/xzcreatetesttype.html?execution=e2s1&amp;_eventId=addtut&amp;tutid=81&amp;tutname=Algebra%20One">Add</a></td>
 <td>Algebra One</td>
   </tr>
```

However, this refreshes the whole page. How do I make this an ajax call so I just refresh the one fragment (i.e., the parent's specified children).

NOTE: My question is about forming the call to webflow. I know how to [render the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342569/spring4-webflow-thymeleaf2-tiles-ajax-everything-works-except)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to the question asked here. I am not sure whether the javascript params fragments argument is necessary as the fragments to render are specified in webflows "render fragments." The function seems to work without this argument.

```html
<table id="bodyInnerTable"
 style="border: 1px solid #007589; width: 100%; vertical-align: top">
 <tr>
  <td id="bodyMainCellHead" colspan="2" th:text="#{label.availabletuts}">Name</td>

 </tr>
 
 <!-- Iterate through the children (retrieved from db and held in bean as TreeMap) 
 Each <a> tag must have a unique th:id. The name attribute applies to all children in list
 
 -->
 <tr th:each="tut : ${vwNewTestType.tutMap}" th:if="${vwNewTestType.tutMap.size() > 0}">
  <td><a th:id="${tut.value}" name="addtutname"
   th:href="@{'~' + ${flowExecutionUrl}(_eventId=addtut, tutid=${tut.value},tutname=${tut.key})}">Add</a></td>
  <td th:text="${tut.key}">id</td>
 </tr>
</table>


<!-- dojo .forEach will then allow for identification of which element  is clicked and the webflow transition on=""addtut" is called-->

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 
 dojo.query("a[name=addtutname]").forEach(function(element) 
   {
       Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
           elementId: element.id,
           event: "onclick"
           //params: {  fragments:"s2,s4"}
       }))
   });
</script>
```